# how to hide dropdown md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to Hide AutoComplete Dropdown after selected item i try many types but not success , anyone help me this , highly appreciated

```
<md-autocomplete  id="autocomplete"  st-search="campaign_name"
                            ng-disabled="Ctrlmain.isDisabled"
                            md-no-cache="true"
                            md-selected-item="Ctrlmain.selectedItem"
                            md-search-text="Ctrlmain.campaignname"
                            md-selected-item-change="Ctrlmain.filltextbox(item)"
                            md-items="item in Ctrlmain.getMatches(Ctrlmain.campaignname)  | unique:'campaign_name'"
                            md-item-text="item.campaign_name"
                            md-min-length="0"
                            placeholder="Search Campaign"
                            md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
                                <md-item-template>
                                    <span class="item-title">                                
                                        <span> {{item.campaign_name}} </span>
                                    </span>
                                </md-item-template>
                        </md-autocomplete>
```

Angularjs Code

```
filltextbox(st){ 
        var autoChild = document.getElementById('autocomplete').firstElementChild;
        console.log(autoChild)
        var el = angular.element(autoChild);
        console.log(el)
        el.scope().$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true;

       // return st;


      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to hide md-autocomplete dropdown when selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732989/how-to-hide-md-autocomplete-dropdown-when-selected-item)

Answer (score 0):

I find in these scenarios it is often another $digest or DOM affecting async function that gets in the way of the standard close logic working. The quick hack is to try to close the dialog after a $timeout.

If you have other async processes running on the page, perhaps like executing a search query, and while the search is running a full screen loader is written into the DOM then it might be necessary to set the $timeout delay to a larger value than usual.

The following snippet tries to force the close immediately, *and* after a timeout to cover all bases, I use this for my md-autocompletes that are serving as a search input with best bet suggestions as well as search results.

```
filltextbox(st){ 
        closeAutocomplete();
        $timeout(closeAutocomplete, 100);

    // return st;
}
closeAutocomplete () {
    var autoChild = document.getElementById('autocomplete').firstElementChild;
    var el = angular.element(autoChild);
    el.scope().$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true;
}
```

For good measure, I make sure the other async functions that operate on the page also call closeAutocomplete. You could wrap the immediate and $timeout logic into a single call like this that allows you to pass in a variable delay

```
closeAutocomplete (delay) {
    // declare function once, only one point to maintain
    var fn = function() {
        var autoChild = document.getElementById('autocomplete').firstElementChild;
        var el = angular.element(autoChild);
        el.scope().$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true;
    };

    fn(); // immediate
    if(!delay) delay = 100;
    $timeout(fn, delay);
}
```